# dygraph gallery doesn't run

Tags: dygraphs, demo

I tried to have some examples for the dygraph library, but when I go to http://dygraphs.com/gallery/, there's nothing on the screen.

I work with Chrome, and in the javascript console, I see those messages:

```
dygraph-dev.js:48     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null          
synchronizer.js:35    Uncaught ReferenceError: Dygraph is not defined
textarea.js:122       Uncaught ReferenceError: Dygraph is not defined
/dygraph-combined.js.map:1    GET http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-combined.js.map 404 (Not Found)
```

Could you help me to get the gallery in order?

Comment: A reference to a specific example would br helpful

Comment: Browser version? Operating System? That page works fine for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I removed the following snippet at end of the JavaScript file and it works now.

```
//# sourceMappingURL=dygraph-combined.js.map
```

In Rails, I guess application.js tries to include that file owing to the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The map file is used to allow unminification :-) of the compacted code.
The "comment" is ignored by Firefox, but respected by chrome, so chrome will try to resolve this file and get an 404.

This is not harmful, as the page still keeps working and I don't consider it bad to remove this last line (for production at least).

BTW, this *.map behaviour can be found in many js frameworks. And usually there is a map file that can be downloaded additinally. For Development I definately prefer non-minified code (for obvious reasons) and use compacted only when the performance is needed.